# I am having trouble with the logic in my code in android studio

Tags: android, mysql

This code is supposed to serve on purpose, to verify that an email address that has been added to the database of "profiles" has not been entered before. After the user enters the relevant data, and attempts to verify the data as a legitimate entry, the email address is checked against other entries in the database (because emails are usually the most unique part of a set of entries other than the nickname)and if the email is unique to the database, the entry is accepted and a new column should be created in the database(which it is). The problem is that the email is always accepted as unique.

This code shows how the entries are weeded out to make sure they fit the convention of sign up sheets

```
public void registerAccount(View view) {
    LoginEntries entries = new LoginEntries(
            newEmailAddressInput.getText().toString(),
            newPasswordInput.getText().toString(),
            newFirstNameInput.getText().toString(),
            newLastNameInput.getText().toString(),
            newNickname.getText().toString(),fullPhoneNumber);
    String isTempEmail = newEmailAddressInput.getText().toString();

    String isTempPass = newPasswordInput.getText().toString();
    String confirmPasswordHolder = confirmNewPasswordInput.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempEmail) && TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempEmail) && TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } /*Temporary while app is offline, when app will be operational, different prompt will search web to verify email address*/
    else if (!isTempEmail.endsWith("@gmail.com") && !isTempEmail.endsWith("@yahoo.com") && !isTempEmail.endsWith("@aol.com") && !isTempEmail.endsWith("@hotmail.com")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not a valid email address, trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (!dbHandler.signUpEmailCheck(isTempEmail)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email used, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (!confirmPasswordHolder.equals(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
        areaCodeInput.setText("");
        firstThreeDigitsInput.setText("");
        finalFourDigitsInput.setText("");
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dbHandler.addEntry(entries);// adds entries to database
        printDatabase();
       }
}
```

this code, which is in the above method is the issue at hand. When the email is handed over to this code, it calls the method below from the database handler class.

```
else if (!dbHandler.signUpEmailCheck(isTempEmail)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email used, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
            newPasswordInput.setText("");
            confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
```

This method takes the email entry and uses it to call any and all other entries with the same name (as i understand it to work, i could be wrong which is why I am writing this question)
if the getColumnCount() function is anything but zero, the method returns true which shows makes the if statement false, which dictates the user to use another email. This never happens. I've tried with different positions of the true, false returns, but none of the combinations lead to the right conclusion.

```
   public boolean signUpEmailCheck(String emailEntry){
    //checks if a new email entry already exists in the database

    Integer holder;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS  + "=\"" + emailEntry + "\"";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    holder = c.getColumnCount();
    if (holder > 0) {
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the method that is called to enter the data into the database

```
public void addEntry(LoginEntries entry){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS,entry.get_emailAddress());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,entry.get_password());
    values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME,entry.get_firstName());
    values.put(COLUMN_LASTNAME,entry.get_lastName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONENUMBER,entry.get_phoneNumber());
    values.put(COLUMN_NICKNAME,entry.get_nickname());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGINENTRIES, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite your query like this, also make sure `emailEntry` is not `null`.

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS  + "=?";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { emailEntry });
```

Also just check if the cursor is empty with the following methods:

```
if(!c.moveToFirst() || c.getCount() == 0){
    ...
    return true; // cursor is empty, the email doesn't exist
}else{
    return false; // cursor is not empty, the email exists
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can finally move on to the other 50 bugs haha.
one question, how does  !c.moveToFirst() come in to play?

Comment: `moveToFirst()` will return false if the cursor is empty. Please accept my answer if it helped you to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just did.